# Can salesforce career be sought without strong coding skills?

Tags: learning

I am an HR professional with over 10 yrs of experience with no background of any coding. I recently came to know that there is no career for folks like us with no coding exposure. Is that true?

Can we pursue a Salesforce career without in depth coding skills?

Comment: The answer depends on how far you intent to delve into salesforce's inner workings. If your career consists of data entry, setting up new salesforce objects, and generally using the point and click interface of salesforce, you can pursue a career doing exactly that. If you are looking to get into deeper salesforce customization such as apex and visualforce, without training, its difficult- but not impossible. You will have to step up and learn these things on your own, but with time, you would be able to pursue those as well. Think hard about where you want this career to take you.

Comment: Theoretically subjective questions aren't a good fit for this site ([what not to ask](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask-)) and are closed. Yet as this question can very clearly be answered with "yes", we'll let it pass :-).

Comment: Thank you all for being so elaborate and precise. You have cleared the air about lot of queries going through my brain...

Answer (score 7):

You do not have to be an engineer to drive a car...

Salesforce is designed for building native apps or managing the platform without having programming knowledge just using the web interface and [declarative  application framework](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Application_Framework).

> The Application Framework lets you customize existing applications or
>   build applications from scratch without writing any code.

You can even achieve Force.com Developer credential without having to write any code:

> A candidate for this exam is not expected to be able to develop code
>   using the Apex programming language

Or just become an Force.com administrator. In this case you will have to learn applications, features and functions available to an end user, and the configuration and management options available to an administrator across
the Sales, Service, and Collaboration Clouds.

Take a look at the [Force.com Fundamentals](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force_Platform_Fundamentals) and learn more how to become an Salesforce professional developer or administrator.

So from my point of view yes, you can start without programming background. Just dive in an learn!

Comment: Please note, that the Force.com Fundamentals book is boring as hell and written in annoying manner, but it is worth reading anyway.

Comment: @BartJuriewicz I do NOT agree. I've found that book very interesting and it is a key for the developer certification door.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

For a very simply reason: **sales*f*orce is an ecosystem.**

And it's big. You've got the sales cloud, service cloud, market cloud, analytics cloud, the platform itself, heroku and the list goes on. There's a huge demand for talent and expertise, which is definitely not limited to code related skills. The declarative nature of the platform, all it's apps and implementations mean that there's a lot to do without even touching code.

A simplified list of possible roles or jobs you could do within the salesforce ecosystem without code skills (**everyone:feel free to add)**

- administrator (maintain an implementation)
- business-analist  (translate business requirements to salesforce features)
- community manager (chatter/customer communities)
- subject matter specialist (specialize in a specific set of salesforce features: for instance the sales cloud, marketing cloud, analytics,..)
- declarative app developer
- ...

Answer (score 3):

tl;dr: Yes. You can pursue a career in the Salesforce ecosystem without coding skills.

Two or three years ago there was a period in which many large consulting partners were hiring experienced Salesforce administrators to work alongside developers to implement solutions. These administrators understood how to use the point-and-click tools to translate business requirements into Salesforce implementations. They didn't necessarily know how to write Apex or Visualforce or JavaScript.

Understanding when you need to use a point-and-click too versus code is useful, as is understanding how to communicate when working with a developer. But there are many customizations that can be done without code.

Someone else suggested the Force.com Fundamentals book -- another suggestion is the free *Getting Started with the Force.com Platform* and *Intro to Visual App Development* Trailhead trainings. https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead

Answer (score 1):

To echo others -- it is 100% possible.

I have zero technical background, got a BA at undergrad and spent the first bit of my career in sales. Eventually I took a junior operations role & started to learn about Salesforce and the declarative functionality. In time, I chose to advance my skill set an began to teach myself the more technical/programmatic part of Salesforce.

I was 100% successful in my Salesforce career before ever choosing to learn the development piece. I still spend a majority of my time in an operational role, and very little time doing development work.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is that it's possible only for simple using saleforce.  Without salesforse you can't customize its solutions. Using only standard functionality do not enough. But there are many documentations, books, posts about saleforce workflow. There is beautiful community which help to solve you problem. Begin to learn apex, sql and SOQL, read documentation and ask questions ...